# statistical significance after NMDS in r

Tags: r, statistical-significance, multidimensional-scaling, vegan

I have performed an Non-metric multidimensional scaling (NMDS) to see if my two stations were different in terms of plankton abundances, using the metaMDS function in r (before I have performed a sqrt transformation). I have done 4 NMDS, one for each season (winter, spring, summer and autumn). I put one of them, just for an example (red and blue points are for the two sites). I would like to know now if the difference that I am seeing from the graph is significant or not. I am a little bit confused about the approach I should consider now...it would be enough to use something like a kruskal-wallis test? Or it would be better something like an anosim or a simper analysis?

Does anyone have any suggestion?
[image]
Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused as well. The only thing I'm sure of is that stay six feet away from Kruskal-Wallis. Once I get an idea what you want to do, I may give a more positive answer. My apologies (I wouldn't like to think I'm a bad person, but if the evidence shows...). Things are more-or-less simple for one ordination, but what actually is your testing model for four ordinations? Within season, between season, interaction? Some things that are sure: do not touch anosim, and stay a light year away from simper (and simper pretends to test quite different things – and fails even there).

Comment: Permanova or CCA may be appropriate, but it's hard to say without knowing what it is you want to test.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I would like to see if there is a difference between my two stations within the seasons (so considering each season separately, for example if the winter season defferentiates between the two stations) considering the abundances of my four groups of organisms. I see differences from the NMDS graphs and I would like to "check if these differences are real! I am also doing diversity indeces (for each season separately). Hope I have been more clear now, thank you again!